# Breakpoint on page reload in javascript

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am debugging foreign complicated js code. There is button, when I press it, page gets reloaded, but that shouldn't happen. When I break inside click handler, it executes completely and page repload/refresh happens after it has finished. After I exit handler, I get into jquery depth. How can I track wich piece of code makes page reload? Thanx!

Comment: Does the click handler use `preventDefault` to cancel the event at the end? If not, then it's the default action for buttons to reload the page.

Comment: No, you are wrong. This <button type="button" >Click Me!</button> one doesn't reload anything.

Comment: First things first. Check the *Error Console* if there's any error.

Comment: Chrome, at least, generates a POST request for plain buttons (`<button>Click me!</button>`) If you add a `type="button"` to your declaration, does the reload go away?

Comment: Mihai, you are wrong again, just verified it here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_button_test , you can try it yourself.

Comment: Nothing gets to the console. Console gets erased and page gets reloadded...

Comment: By the way, Mihai if I add type="button", the problem goes away. Would you be so kind to explain why may this happen (including my try to reproduce this in w3school.com)? You may post it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanx!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the `<button>` declaration didn't include the `type` attribute. Here's [what the HTML standard says about that:](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#attr-button-type)

> The type attribute controls the behavior of the button when it is
>   activated. It is an enumerated attribute. The following table lists
>   the keywords and states for the attribute — the keywords in the left
>   column map to the states in the cell in the second column on the same
>   row as the keyword.
>
> ```
> +---------+---------------+--------------------+
> | Keyword |     State     |  Brief description |
> +---------+---------------+--------------------+
> | submit  | Submit Button | Submits the form.  |
> | reset   | Reset Button  | Resets the form.   |
> | button  | Button        | Does nothing.      |
> +---------+---------------+--------------------+
> ```
>
> The missing value default is the Submit Button state.
>
> If the type attribute is in the Submit Button state, the element is
>   specifically a submit button.

A submit button's default action is to submit the form to the server (thus reloading the page). To prevent that, you needed to either specify the `type="button"` attribute on your button, or [prevent the default action in your click handler.](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

[JSFiddle showing all cases.](http://jsfiddle.net/57C7x/)